# How to remove searched entry from array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am creating a angular application, which has one li with ng-repeat and a text box for searching the out put in ng-repeat, the repeated item has a delete "X" button which deletes the record from DB. problem i am facing is how to remove searched record from the array using splice.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oPBofD2wL2ZUrD23f8Rr?p=preview

go to above plnkr click on any of the "x" without searching, then it will get removed from the list . but when you search for something lets say ruby then only ruby will come into the list but by clicking on "x" it will still appear . I need help in removing the searched field from the array using array operation, i dont want to regenerate that array again.

Comment: Why should I visit plunker? __Questions at SO should be complete.__ Always post you code here.

Comment: @Mayray Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are sending the $index for removing, instead of that pass the id like

```
 <a href="" ng-click="delete(project.id)">X</a>
```

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9hQVYSb9MjGTrXYPaY2R?p=preview)**

Try this out

```
$scope.delete = function(idx) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.projects.length; i++){
    if ($scope.projects[i].id === idx)
     {
         $scope.projects.splice(i, 1);
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked, but not sure which one is efficient ..please see below solutions as well

Answer (score 5):

instead of just using the index as a parameter, calculate your index with a search of the json element in the array.

Like so:

```
$scope.delete = function(project) {
  idx = $scope.projects.indexOf(project);
  $scope.projects.splice(idx, 1);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yn6GQ6zScw4dZ59lkP2k?p=preview)

Comment: I have added plunker link with your question, Reveret back if you don't want that

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine .. so out of indexOF solution  and beow solution by passing ID , which one is efficient $scope.delete = function(idx) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.projects.length; i++){
    if ($scope.projects[i].id === idx)
     {
         $scope.projects.splice(i, 1);
     }
  }
};

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `idx` is set to `$index`. That is the index of the `ng-repeat`, not the index of the array so when the list is filtered you're now deleting the wrong element.
(You'll notice this if you clear the search-box after deleting)

If you change your HTML to

```
<a href="" ng-click="delete(project)">X</a>
```

The delete function will receive the actual element that needs to be removed and can be rewritten to

```
$scope.delete = function(project) {
  $scope.projects.splice($scope.projects.indexOf(project), 1)
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. it worked can u pls tell me which one is efficient finding index of the passed project or the one which Nadhish has posted  ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682951/why-is-looping-through-an-array-so-much-faster-than-javascripts-native-indexof